# Capital Appendices in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I'm fairly new to latex and I am trying to prepare my thesis document by using Latex. Unfortunately, I have a problem in table of content. In TOC, "Appendices" should be capital like "APPENDICES". Thank you very much for your help,

Current TOC:
[image]

Related part in cls file:
[image]

And, this is what I want:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shown what you have, or have not, done. Providing an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we could compile that shows your problem would have been a great help; we are not good a guessing.

Perhaps the addition of

```
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{APPENDICES}
```

to your code might help (see the `appendix` manual).  --- GOM

Comment: Sorry about the lack of MWE, I am new for this stuff. Your advice works fine, thank you very much. Is there a way to get rid of dots and page number only for APPENDICES row.